# argc, argv causes strange behavior in Null terminator in C

Tags: c, cs50

when I write:

```
#include <cs50.h> // includes type string
#include <stdio.h>

void trial(string a[])
{
    if(a[2] == '\0')
    {
        printf("Null\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string a[] = {"1","2"};
    trial(a);
}
```

It appears that array of strings does not end with a Null character.

But when I write int main(void), it prints "Null".

Even more strange , when I add return 0; to int main(void) , it does not print "Null".

I don't understand what is happening, in the cs50's lecture code that is below worked :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int len(string s)
{
    int count=0;

    while(s[count] != '\0')
    {
        count++;
    }
   return count;
}


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string s = get_string("Input: \n");

    printf("Length of the string: %d \n",len(s));

    return 0;
}
```

I am aware of the difference between our arrays, mine is array of strings, code above is string which is array of characters. But in some posts I saw that character arrays are not null terminated. But maybe in cs50.h they implemented a string as a array of characters that is terminated with a null character. I am lost.

Comment: *But when I write int main(void), it prints "Null".* what do you mean by that?

Comment: It might be a bit hard to know exactly what's going on as "string" is not standard C, but just as a guess, you may be playing with undefined behavior if you're reading index [2] of an array of size 2, as only indexes 0 and 1 would make sense

Comment: in the trial function variable `a` is an `array` of `string`. why are you comparing it with a character?

Comment: You are confusing the last pointer in an array of pointers (to string) with the last char in an array of chars.

Comment: @scipsycho I am new to C , it is possible to that comparison to be wrong but I thought that it won't be a problem because I am comparing to see if it is null which I thought is same for all types of arrays.

Comment: @Lundin Is cs50 only bad for C, or is it overall a bad course ?

Comment: The C part is bad, I don't know about the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string a[] = {"1","2"}` is a 2-element array. There will be no hidden NULL-pointer appended to it. Accessing `a[2]` (the would-be 3-rd element of it) renders your program undefined. There's not much of a point in analyzing how different variables affect a program whose behavior is undefined. It can vary from compiler to compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    //arrays of char initialized with a string literal end with '\0' because
    //the string literal does
    char const s0[] = "12";
#define NELEMS(Array) (sizeof(Array)/sizeof(*(Array)))
    printf("%zd\n", NELEMS(s0)); //prints 3

    //explicitly initialized char arrays don't silently append anything
    char const s1[] = {'1','2'};
    printf("%zd\n", NELEMS(s1)); //prints 2


    //and neither do array initializations for any other type
    char const* a[] = {"1","2"};
    printf("%zd\n", NELEMS(a)); //prints 2
}
```

Comment: The source code for cs50.h has “typedef char *string;” so that helps. Your text is correct (didn’t check the code)

Comment: @Marichyasana I don't say this often, but in this case, I'm fairly sure my code is correct too :)

Comment: I am too - no offense intended- I’m just being lazy. Gave you +1